# Multiple Masks on Dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 sliders which will multiply an adjusted value at the relevant index using a mask on a series labelled 'code'. I have managed to get the value to adjust with 1 mask but when using multiple i'm unable to do it. If anyone can help that would be greatas i'm new to python and pandas.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider, IntSlider

import pandas as pd

base_val1 = 6500
base_val2 = 13617

def efficiency(number,number2,number3,number4):
    
    baseline_env_cost = 300000
    base_efficiency = base_val1 / base_val2
    print("Baseline efficiency: ",base_efficiency)
    
    min1 = 0.35
    max1 = 0.65
      
    min2 = 0.4
    max2 = 0.9
    
    min3 = 0.2
    max3 = 0.7
    
    min4 = 0.6
    max4 = 1.4
    
    normalised =  (number - min1) / (max1 - min1) # normalises the data range so that 0.35 is 0 and 0.65 is 1
    normalised2 =  (number2 - min2) / (max2 - min2)
    normalised3 =  (number3 - min3) / (max3 - min3)
    normalised4 =  (number4 - min4) / (max4 - min4)
    
    print(normalised,normalised2,normalised3,normalised4)
    
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\david\Documents\test.csv')
    
    # below recalculates the adjusted qty when the slider position changes
    
    df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Code'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.1, df['Quantity'] * normalised, axis=0) #locate all items in Quantity column with Index 2.1 and multiply by Normalised value 
    df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Code'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.2, df['Quantity'] * normalised2, axis=0)
    df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Code'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.3, df['Quantity'] * normalised3, axis=0)
    df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Code'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.4, df['Quantity'] * normalised4, axis=0)
    
    
    df['Adjusted Cost'] = df['Adjusted Qty'] * df['Rate']
    df['Total'] = df['Quantity'] * df['Rate']
         
    total = df['Adjusted Cost'].sum() #totals the entire 'Adjusted Cost Column'
          
    print(df)
    
    
    return 'Revised cost:', total #returns the total cost of the 'Adjusted Cost Column'

slider = FloatSlider(value=0.45, min=0.35, max=0.65, step=0.001)
slider2 = FloatSlider(value=0.6, min=0.4, max=0.9, step=0.001)
slider3 = FloatSlider(value=0.5, min=0.2, max=0.7, step=0.001)
slider4 = FloatSlider(value=0.9, min=0.6, max=1.4, step=0.001)

ipywidgets.interact(efficiency,number=slider, number2=slider2, number3=slider3, number4=slider4);
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you overwrite values of `df['Adjusted Qty']` with each new line, discarding previously generated values.

A minimal required change would be replacing the column you're adjusting to `'Adjusted Qty'`:

```
df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Code'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.1, df['Quantity'] * normalised, axis=0) #locate all items in Quantity column with Index 2.1 and multiply by Normalised value 
df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Adjusted Qty'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.2, df['Quantity'] * normalised2, axis=0)
df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Adjusted Qty'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.3, df['Quantity'] * normalised3, axis=0)
df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Adjusted Qty'].mask(df['Code'] == 2.4, df['Quantity'] * normalised4, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, you can generate the column in one go:

```
multipliers = {
    2.1: normalised,
    2.2: normalised2,
    2.3: normalised3,
    2.4: normalised4,
}

df['Multiplier'] = df['Code'].map(multipliers)
df['Adjusted Qty'] = df['Quantity'] * df['Multiplier']
```